# Dockerized VuJS NGINX 403 error : directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/" is forbidden

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx

I am trying to dockerize a VueJS app using nginx , but it keeps showing me this error .

```
[error] 8#8: *1 directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x:80"
[error] 8#8: *1 directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x:80"
[error] 8#8: *1 directory index of "/etc/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: x.x.x.x, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "x.x.x.x:80"
```

This my docker and nginx configuration :

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine

# Copy built app into nginx 
COPY /dist /etc/nginx/html/studio

# copy nginx conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  map $http_user_agent $loggable {
    "~kube-probe/.*"        0;
    default                 1;
  }
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main if=$loggable;

  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /studio/ {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /studio/index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  }
}
```

When I access the browser it shows : 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable - nginx

Comment: Do you have `/dist` in your server? Or you meant `./dist`?

Comment: the Dockerfile and dist folder are at the same level

Comment: Change it to what I said, either `./dist` or `dist` (without `/` at first) and try again.

Comment: changed it , didn't work :(

Comment: What do you enter in browser? `localhost` or `localhost/studio`? If you enter `localhost`, it's normal you see error because you did not defined anything in `/`.

Comment: no I am using "baseurl"/studio

Comment: I am deploying it on kubernetes  , I use ingress , so it's "hostname"/studio

Comment: According to your config you are setting your app to be available under `http://localhost/studio/` URL, but the error log entries you've shown are about `http://localhost/` which is expected (unless you'd place some `index.html` file under the `/etc/nginx/html` directory, however it isn't required if this setup is only to serve the `/studio/` URI prefix).